# Howto recover SQL 2016 cluster instance with bad tempdb path setting?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, recovery, tempdb

Today I have changed the tempdb's file locations using the `ALTER DATABASE MODIFY` command and I have accidentaly set it to use the **root of the volume**. The SQL Server service failed to restart and came up with Access denied errors in eventlog. It is a 2016 Sp1 failover cluster.
I tried to workaround this using

```
NET START MSSQL$INST1 /f /T3608
```

but it does not work.

What can I do about this? How can I restart the service to get able to re-define the setting to use a subfolder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pinal Dave wrote up a nice article on how to fix this. Have you tried this?

- [How to Start SQL Server Service Without tempdb?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/02/23/sql-server-how-to-start-sql-server-service-without-tempdb/)

> 1. `NET START MSSQLSERVER /f`
> 2. Connect to SQL via `SQLCMD`
> 3. Run `ALTER DATABASE tempdb` command
> 4. Restart SQL Server

From the looks of things you are having an issue starting SQL that is a named instance. This Microsoft article explains how to use that command with a named instance:

- [How to: Start an Instance of SQL Server (net Commands)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187598(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, Restart the Database Engine, SQL Server Agent, or SQL Server Browser Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx)

Are you getting any errors in the error log for the service startup failure?

Comment: I ended using C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MYINST\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe -s MYINST -f to start the service and used SLQCMD to modify the tempdb file settings. After that the failover instances could be started again. TY

Comment: @Magier I honestly don't see how you got to that from the links posted in this answer. Perhaps you should add an answer of your own to show what you actually did, and where you found that information.

Comment: @Paus you are right, very attentive! It's true, while I waited for answers I found anoter page explaining how to get around it and followed it. The solution was almost identical with the answer above. The page is the following: http://sql.richarddouglas.co.uk/archive/2010/08/recovering-tempdb.html#axzz4bDSC5ALI